# How to disable mouse with Ruby Win32API

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm trying to do something like this but only with the mouse:

```
require 'win32api'
BlockInput = Win32API.new("user32", "BlockInput", ["I"], "I")

BlockInput.call(1)
sleep 5
BlockInput.call(0)
```

I'm trying to use [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but it say that work but nothing happens, i can continue moving and clicking my mouse, this is the code:

```
require 'win32/api'

# SetWindowsHookEx CONSTANTS
WH_MOUSE = 7
WH_MOUSE_LL = 14

# MouseProc or LowLevelMouseProc CONSTANTS
WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200
WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201
WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202
WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A
WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E
WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204
WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205

SetWindowsHookEx = Win32::API.new('SetWindowsHookEx', ['I', 'K', 'L', 'I'], 'L', 'user32')
CallNextHookEx = Win32::API.new('CallNextHookEx', ['I', 'I', 'L', 'P'], 'I', 'user32')
UnhookWindowsHookEx = Win32::API.new('UnhookWindowsHookEx', ['I'], 'I', 'user32')
GetCurrentThreadId = Win32::API.new('GetCurrentThreadId', ['V'], 'I', 'kernel32')

MouseProc = Win32::API::Callback.new('ILP', 'L') do |nCode, wParam, lParam|
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)
    if nCode < 0 # If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
        return CallNextHookEx.call(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    elsif wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE or wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN or wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP
        # If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from
        # passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.
        return 1
    else
        # If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message,
        # it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns;
        # otherwise, other applications that have installed WH_MOUSE_LL hooks will not receive hook
        # notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result.
        return CallNextHookEx.call(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    end
end

threadID = GetCurrentThreadId.call
hMod = nil
# If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle to the hook procedure.
p hhk = SetWindowsHookEx.call(WH_MOUSE, MouseProc, hMod, threadID) #=> 166134929 (Good)
# But nothing happens, i can continue moving and clicking my mouse.
sleep 5
p UnhookWindowsHookEx.call(hhk) #=> 1 (Good)
```

if someone knows how to do it or how to do it in another way I would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit**: I'm running the code with admin access on Windows 7 (32 Bits)

I'm trying to use GetMessage() following [Strive Sun - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11128312/strive-sun-msft)'s answer but i have some problems passing MSG pointer

```
GetMessage = Win32::API.new('GetMessage', ['P', 'L', 'L', 'L'], 'I', 'user32')
point = [0, 0].pack('LL')
hwnd = uint = wparam = lparam = dword = 0
buf = [hwnd, uint, wparam, lparam, dword, point, dword].pack('JIL2Sa8S')
# J > hwnd, I > uint, L2 > wparam lparam, S > dword, a8 > point
GetMessage.call(buf, nil, 0, 0) #=> Stuck, i need to use Manager Task to close it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lack a message loop.

Please refer: [MouseProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> An application-defined or library-defined callback function used with
>   the SetWindowsHookEx function. The system calls this function whenever
>   an application calls the [GetMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN) or [PeekMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function and there
>   is a mouse message to be processed.

**Why must SetWindowsHookEx be used with a windows message queue?**

> As [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460728/11128312) said that, the low-level hooks, `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and
>   `WH_MOUSE_LL` are different from all the other hooks. They don't
>   require a `DLL` to be injected into the target process. Instead,
>   Windows calls your hook callback directly, inside your own process. To
>   make that work, a message loop is required. There is no other
>   mechanism for Windows to make callbacks on your main thread, the
>   callback can only occur when you've called `Get/PeekMessage()` so that
>   Windows is in control.
>
> A global hook like `WH_KEYBOARD` is very different. It requires a
>   `DLL` and the callback occurs within the process that processes the
>   keyboard message. You need some kind of inter-process communication to
>   let your own program be aware of this. Named pipes are the usual
>   choice. Which otherwise of course requires that this injected process
>   pumps a message loop. It wouldn't get keyboard messages otherwise.
>
> Favor a low-level hook, they are much easier to get going. But do pump
>   or it won't work. And beware of timeouts, if you're not responsive
>   enough then Windows will kill your hook without notice.

If you need to use `WH_MOUSE` globally, please inject the DLL.
If you don't want to use DLL, please use `WH_MOUSE_LL` instead of `WH_MOUSE`.

For more details ,please refer : [Use WH_MOUSE globally without DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253585/use-wh-mouse-globally-without-dll)

This is C++ code and works. Because I am not familiar with Ruby, I cannot provide modified Ruby code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HHOOK mouseHook;

LRESULT __stdcall MouseHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL :
            return 1;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            return 1;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            return 1;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    if (!(mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Failed to install mouse hook!" << endl;
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHook);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is so useful, i'm trying to use GetMessage() but i have some problems passing MSG pointer, if someone can help me i would appreciate it.
I edited the main post to add the code.

Comment: Maybe knowing the size of MSG could be useful, can you tell me it?

Comment: @Andrek Do you mean `sizeof(MSG)`? Its value is 28.

Comment: I really don't know what to do, i'm passing to my GetMessage a 28 bytesize string but it keeps stuck, well thanks a lot :).